# how to make sprite node return to same place after "jumping"?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

So I have a `SpriteNode` that jumps up and to the right when tapped. That's all great but when it jumps it lands to the right. If I keep tapping it it will jump off the screen.

I need the sprite to jump up and to the right and return to the place where it started. A kind of diagonal jump rather than an arc. How do I do this?

My code:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {

            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            savior.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0) //pt it returns to?
            savior.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(5, 30)) //direction/height that it jumps

            if UIDevice().iPhone6plus {
                savior.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0) //pt it returns to?
                savior.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 12)) //direction/height that it jumps

            }
            if UIDevice().iPad2 {
                savior.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0) //pt it returns to?
                savior.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 140)) //direction/height that it jumps

            }

        }
```

Comment: Diagonal? Do you mean vertical?

Comment: Not really. I don't want it to jump straight up- i need it to jump to the side and back to the same place again.

Comment: do you mean that you want your character to move diagonally (in a slanted line) to a certain height and retrace the same line back to the initial position? Does this mean that the character will never move from the initial position ?

Comment: As you noticed, physics isn't the right thing to use when you want objects to go to specific (exact) positions. Either you live with that and design the game accordingly, or don't use physics and implement the movement behavior manually (ie using actions).

Comment: @LearnCocos2D yeah, I realized actions were the way to go. Thanks.